# Arithmetic operations on large dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Apologies in advance if this isn't a good question, I'm a beginner in DataFrames...

I have a large dataframe (about a thousands rows and 5000+ columns).

The first 5000 columns contain numbers, and I need to do some operations on each of these numbers based on the values of other columns.

For instance multiply the 5000 first numbers on a row with the value of another column on the same row.

| Index | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... | 5000 | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.1 | 0.4 | 0.8 | 0.6 | ... | 0.3 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 9 |
| 1 | 0.7 | 0.5 | 0.4 | 0.8 | ... | 0.1 | 4 | 6 | 1 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1000 | 0.2 | 0.5 | 0.1 | 0.9 | ... | 0.6 | 6 | 8 | 5 | 4 |

This is an example of code that is multiplying my numbers by the column "a", then muliply by a constant and then get the exponential of that :

```
a_col = df.get_loc("a")
            
df.iloc[: , : 5000 ] = np.exp (df.iloc[: ,  : 5000 ] * df.iloc[: , [a_col]].to_numpy() * np.sqrt(4) )
```

While the results look fine, it does feel slow, especially compared to the code I'm trying to replace that was doing these operations rows by rows in a loop.

Is this the proper way to do what I'm trying to achieve, or am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. What's `get_col`?

Comment: Do you mean get_loc ? It's to get the column number for "a".

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant `get_col`. I have a normal (pandas version 1.3.4) DataFrame called `df`, and `df.get_loc("a")` says `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_loc'`. I did `df["a"]` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, but see my answer below. It's very fast considering the size of the data (`5k * 1k = 1m`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.values` method to get the numpy arrays, `np.newaxis` to make `df.a` a column vector and multiply row-wise:

```
df.iloc[: , : 5000 ] = np.exp(df.iloc[: ,  : 5000 ].values * df.a.values[:, np.newaxis] * np.sqrt(4) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.iloc[:, :5000] = np.exp(df.iloc[:, :5000].values * a_col.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1) * np.sqrt(4))
```

It took just a few seconds to run (for the 5 million cells).

If it works, I'll explain it :)